# Length Conditions for R Table Subset

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, dataframe

I have a `data.table` in R where ID is a column. Some of the IDs are 3 digits long and some are 4 digits long. I want to create a new table where only those columns that are not 4 digits long are able to be easily inspected. How do I loop through just the rows of column $ID and test for length?

```
       Index ID age education gender relationship
       3    6192  32        12      2            2
       4    6191  18        NA      1           NA
       6    8421  25        10      1            2
       7     999  18        NA      1           NA
       9    7612  35        12      2            1
       10   7611  43        14      1            1
       11   8422  51        11      2            2
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example to work with on questions like these http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
DT = data.table(x=rep(c("b","a","c"),each=3), y=c(1,3,6), v=1:9, ID=c(123,1234,123,123,123))
```

> ```
>    x y v   ID
> 1: b 1 1  123
> 2: b 3 2 1234
> 3: b 6 3  123
> 4: a 1 4  123
> 5: a 3 5  123
> 6: a 6 6  123
> 7: c 1 7 1234
> 8: c 3 8  123
> 9: c 6 9  123
> ```

```
subset(DT, !nchar(DT$ID)==4 )
```

> ```
>    x y v  ID
> 1: b 1 1 123
> 2: b 6 3 123
> 3: a 1 4 123
> 4: a 3 5 123
> 5: a 6 6 123
> 6: c 3 8 123
> 7: c 6 9 123
> ```

```
DT1 <- subset(DT, !nchar(DT$ID)==4 )

DT1
```

> ```
>    x y v  ID
> 1: b 1 1 123
> 2: b 6 3 123
> 3: a 1 4 123
> 4: a 3 5 123
> 5: a 6 6 123
> 6: c 3 8 123
> 7: c 6 9 123
> ```

Finally, if your ID data type is not a character just do it like this `DT1 <- subset(DT, !nchar(as.character(DT$ID))==4 )`.

Comment: The column is all integers so nchar throws this error `Error in nchar(data$ID) : 'nchar()' requires a character vector`

Comment: @HeatherCohen You can just use `as.character()`. I'm not saying to actually change the data type just use it in the comparison. `subset(DT, !nchar(as.character(DT$ID))==4 )`. I've updated my answer accordingly. Groovy?

Answer (score 1):

If `ID` is numeric, `floor(log10(ID))` will do.

```
floor(log10(c(1, 10, 11, 100, 101)))
# [1] 0 1 1 2 2
```

And if `ID` is a character vector, then `nchar` will tell you how long each string is.

```
nchar(c("1", "10", "11", "100", "101"))
# [1] 1 2 2 3 3
```

Comment: I get the error `Error in Math.factor(data$ID) : ‘log10’ not meaningful for factors" when I try to use floor(log10(data$ID))`

nchar gives me `Error in nchar(data$ID) : 'nchar()' requires a character vector`

Comment: Then convert it to character before using `nchar`